# problems using free for a struct of dynamic arrays

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc, free

I can't undestand why it gives me a Seg-Fault while processing the following code in C:

here is the type and declaration:

```
typedef struct Tcell { char* left;
             char* right;
            struct Tcell* next;} Tcell;


Tcell* T;

T=malloc(sizeof(Tcell));
T->right=malloc(sizeof(string2) + sizeof(char)*10); //string2 is a dynamic string of chars.
T->left=malloc(sizeof(char)*11);
strcpy(L->right, string2); 
L->left="_";
free(T->left);
free(T->right);
free(T);
```

aaaaand i get a Seg-Fault at the first (and the second free)

Can't seem to find the answer anywhere :S

Comment: The problem is probably in the part where you "use them in the program", which you don't show us. So please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Can you proof that all three pointers are non-NULL at the point of freeing and have not changed, e.g. to left=left+1... and most importantly have not already been freed?

Comment: Please don't tell a story, but provide the MCVE and all information as specified by [ask].

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always equal to 1, so you can skip it. You don't check if malloc failed (but that's not the problem, free(NULL) is ok to do). So, the code you showing us should "working". Your bug lies somewhere on code that you don't show us. Provide an MVCE please.

Comment: @Tom's: `T->…` will invoke UB nevertheless. But OP seems not to be interested to provide all required information and a MCVE, so we should let it be.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite Aaaaah, I forgot the case if the malloc of T failed, you're rigth.

Comment: @LeonTrotsky: You better had checked the type of `T` before posting this.

Comment: Yes sorry if i didn't provide all the informations.

Comment: I added the part after which it goes in Segmentation fault.

Comment: what do you expect `malloc(string2 + x)` to do? malloc neesa number as input, not a pointer to a string

Comment: whoops ,edited ...

Comment: sizeof(string2) is the sizeof char pointer. you can try using strlen(string2) instead

Answer (score 0):

As @Yunnosch mentioned in comment section, before free dynamic memory you might have modified the pointer.

For example below code gives Segmentation fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct Tcell {
    char* left;
    char* right;
    struct Tcell* next;
} Tcell;


int main(){
    Tcell *T;
    T=malloc(sizeof(Tcell));
    assert(T != NULL);
    T->right=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    assert(T->right != NULL);
    T->left=malloc(sizeof(char)*11);
    assert(T->left != NULL);

    printf("check\n");
    T = T-> next;

    free(T->left);
    free(T->right);
    free(T);
    return 0;
}
```

When you remove the line

> ```
> T = T-> next;
> ```

it goes fine.

So like this you might have modified your T in your code.

Comment: sorry for not providing the code . i edited to show where i get the problem